# AVERAGE multiple rows in a column in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following tables:

```
Table 1
Student , Exam_ID
1      1      
2      1     
3      2     
1      2     
3      3     
2      3     
3      4     
1      4  

Table 2
Exam ID, Mark
(1   , 5)
(2 ,   4)
(3  ,  4)
(4 ,   5)
```

each exam is solved by pairs of students ... i want to be able to average the mark of all exams taken by each pair of student for example :  Exams 2 and 4 are taken by the same pair of students (3,1) i want to be able to average the marks for those 2 exams which are(4,5)=4.5
and then rank those pairs from highest to lowest marks
thank you

**How can I include First_Name and Surname into the first table?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    a.Student AS studentA
  , b.Student AS studentB
  , AVG(T2.Mark) AS averageMark
FROM ( T2
      INNER JOIN T1 AS a
          ON a.Exam_ID = T2.Exam_ID
     )  
      INNER JOIN T1 AS b
          ON a.Exam_ID = b.Exam_ID
          AND a.Student < b.Student
GROUP BY a.Student
       , b.Student
ORDER BY AVG(T2.Mark) DESC
```

or this:

```
SELECT
    a.Student AS studentA
  , b.Student AS studentB
  , AVG(T2.Mark) AS averageMark
FROM ( T1 AS a
      INNER JOIN T1 AS b
          ON a.Exam_ID = b.Exam_ID
          AND a.Student < b.Student
     )
      INNER JOIN T2
          ON a.Exam_ID = T2.Exam_ID
GROUP BY a.Student
       , b.Student
ORDER BY AVG(T2.Mark) DESC
```

where it is more obvious how it works. The JOIN inside the parenthesis finds the couples and next JOIN relates the couples to the second Marks table.

Comment: it says a word in select is reserved or misspelled n it highlights b. Student

Comment: Corrected. 2 commas were missing, INNER JOIN instead of (just) JOIN

Comment: btw table 1 and table 2 are not directly related

Comment: it still says that b. is reserved

Comment: Have you copied the exact query as it is above?

Comment: now i want to order the students by another critirea which is from another table: i want the pair of students to be ordered by teacher's review, the techer also bases her review on the exam which is in another table .. how can i do that??

Comment: Better post it as a separate question, adding in the description that table with a few sample rows (as you have done here).

Comment: You could also add a link to this question as the two questions are related.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863831/access-sql-average-three-columns this is the new question

Comment: How can I include first_Name and Surname into the first table?