# access sql average three columns

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following tables:

```
Table 1
Student , Exam_ID
1      1      
2      1     
3      2     
1      2     
3      3     
2      3     
3      4     
1      4  

Table 2
Exam ID, Mark
(1   , 5)
(2 ,   4)
(3  ,  4)
(4 ,   5)

Table 3
Exam ID, Teacher's review
(1,3)
(2,5)
(3,4)
(4,2)

Table 4
Exam_ID, Start_Time, End_Time
(1,2:00:00,3:50:00)
(2,2:00:00,4:00:00)
(3,3:00:00,5:20:00)
(4,3:00:00,5:00:00)
```

each exam is solved by pairs of students ... i want to be able to average the marks, Teacher's review, of all exams taken by each pair of student for example :  Exams 2 and 4 are taken by the same pair of students (3,1) i want to be able to average the marks for those 2 exams which are(4,5)=4.5 and Teacher's review (5,2)=3.5
and then rank those pairs from highest to lowest marks and teacher's review and be able to calculate the difference between start and end time for each exam and include this in ranking as well
so the required table would be like:

```
StudentA, StudentB, AverageMark, AverageTeacher'sReview, AverageExamDuration
( 3,       1,        4.5,           3.5,                     2:00:00)
```

etc

Related question: [average-multiple-rows-in-a-column-in-access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5862953/average-multiple-rows-in-a-column-in-access/)

thank you

Comment: homework?  if so, add the homework tag.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like homework, the != in the first join is probably what you are supposed to learn if so.

```
select A.StudentId as StudentA, 
B.StudentId as StudentB,
AVG(Mark) as AvgMark,
AVG(review) as AvgReview, 
AVG(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,StartTime,EndTime)) as AvgTime
from StudentToExam A 
inner join StudentToExam B on A.ExamId = B.ExamId and A.StudentId != B.StudentId
inner join ExamToMark M on A.ExamId = M.ExamId
inner join ExamToReview R on A.ExamId = R.Review
inner join ExamDuration D on D.ExamId = A.ExamId
GROUP BY A.StudentId, B.StudentId
```

Comment: it says there is a mistake in the FROM clause

Comment: @Tantoon: The query is correct (almost) but Access is picky about how you write your queries. You have two choices. Either use parenthesis in the inner joins or change Access options to accept only SQL Server compatible syntax (ANSI 92). This will require to have all your queries in that syntax.

Comment: @Tantoon, @Eric: I say almost because I'd prefer to have that `!=` changed into `<`. The way it is now, all couples will be shown twice. (which may be good if you want that).